# How to create responsive font-sizing to match container

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I'm trying to resize the font to the container, to be kept in a single line not matter how long  is, just by resizing it's font.

this is what I'm talking about

```
#project_stats{

padding: 0;
width: 320px;
margin: 0;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;


    pr1 {
    font-size: 2vw; overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

---- EDIT 1 ------

Html.

```
<% provide(:title, @project.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="project_canvas">
    <div class="row">
      <div class = "col-md-3" id="project_stats">
        <pr1><%= @project.name %></pr1>
         ........
```

Update to CSS

```
#project_canvas{

  background: white;
  width: 1600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: rgb(150,150,150) 5px 5px 10px;

    #project_stats{

    padding: 0;
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;


    pr1 {
    font-size: 2vw; overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question, and you need to post HTML for us to help. Your CSS looks fine, except it's nested (which won't work unless you are using a preprocessor like Sass/SCSS), and there's no such HTML tag as `pr1` (did you mean a class or ID, which would be `.pr1` or `#pr1`?).

Comment: I see it. Your CSS is still nested. Are you using a preprocessor?

Comment: No, I'm not using any preprocessor more than css bootstrap (I'm quite a new to rails).

Comment: You'll need to separate your three CSS elements so they aren't contained within one another. Each set of curly braces should end before another is introduced.

Comment: If the title content is dynamic, you'll have a hard time doing this with CSS.  There are JS solutions to this problem however, such as http://jquery-textfill.github.io/

Comment: @Axel Superb! I'll have a look and post my answer If I manage hahah thanks!